# Terraform dynamic json content

Tags: json, terraform

> Environment : Terraform 0.12.X

If variable var.cloudfront_distributionId is not empty then this should add cloudfront policy
else should not

```
locals {

    codebuild_policy = {
        Version = "2012-10-17"
        Statement = [
         {
              Effect = "Allow",
              Resource = [
                        "*"
               ],
               Action = [
                "ec2:*"
               ]
        },
        {
                #count = length(var.cloudfront_distributionId) != 0 ? 1 : 0
                effect = "Allow",
                Action = [
                    "cloudfront:ListInvalidations",
                    "cloudfront:GetInvalidation",
                    "cloudfront:CreateInvalidation"
                  ],
                Resource = [
                  for cf_id in  var.cloudfront_distributionId:
                  "arn:aws:cloudfront::xxxxxxxx:distribution/${cf_id}"
                ]
              }
    ]
    }
}


resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "codebuild" {
  count  = local.env_build_resource.count
  name   = "${var.namespace}-${var.environment}-${var.service_name}"
  role   = element(aws_iam_role.codebuild.*.name, 0)
  policy = jsonencode(local.codebuild_policy)
}
```

**Example 1**

cloudfront_distributionId = ["1", "2"]

then

Resource = ["1", "2"].  which is **working**

---

**Example 2**
cloudfront_distributionId = [] is empty

It is creating, werein it should not get created.

```
+ {
              + Action   = [
                  + "cloudfront:ListInvalidations",
                  + "cloudfront:GetInvalidation",
                  + "cloudfront:CreateInvalidation",
                ]
              + Resource = []
              + count    = 0
              + effect   = "Allow"
            },
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Why do you expect the policy should not be created if the variable is empty? The `count` field in your resource block doesn't refer to the `cloudfront_distributionId` variable

Comment: Because for dev we do only build. For uat and prod we build and deploy to cloudfront.

Comment: I didn't mean why do you want to do this, I meant what is in your definition that should prevent the policy being created when the variable is an empty list? You have a `count` field in the policy resource, but it refers to some other variable. Replace that with the `count` field in your `locals` block and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

There are some parts missing in your code, thus its difficult to verify the answer form me, but I think the following could be attempted:

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "codebuild" {
  # remaining attributes

  policy =  length(var.cloudfront_distributionId) > 0 ? jsonencode(local.codebuild_policy): null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a JSON-specific question but rather a general question about conditionally including items in a list, because from Terraform's perspective that `Statement` attribute of your object is just a normal list value.

One way to think of this is as the concatenation of two lists, one of which might be empty. We can concatenate lists using [the `concat` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/concat.html), and then use normal [conditional expressions](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) to decide the length of the second list to concatenate:

```
locals {
  codebuild_policy = {
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = concat(
      [
        {
          Effect = "Allow",
          Resource = [
            "*"
          ],
          Action = [
            "ec2:*"
          ]
        },
      ],
      length(var.cloudfront_distributionId) != 0 ? [
        {
          Effect = "Allow",
          Action = [
            "cloudfront:ListInvalidations",
            "cloudfront:GetInvalidation",
            "cloudfront:CreateInvalidation"
          ],
          Resource = [
            for cf_id in var.cloudfront_distributionId :
            "arn:aws:cloudfront::xxxxxxxx:distribution/${cf_id}"
          ]
        }
      ] : [],
    )
  }
}
```